# Why doesn't the short-hand notation work outside class?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Somehow I am not able to understand this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10263140/1465553).

When a member function is defined outside class, why can't we have a simple nested name specifier (for example `Foo::Foo(){}` instead of having a *more verbose* `Foo<T>::Foo(){}`), even after the template declaration is repeated right before the member function definition.

Comment: *templated class* is a misnomer.  It is a class template, which means it is a template for creating a class, it is not a class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtlety is that in

```
template<class T>
int VisitedSet::getSize() {
   return vec.size();
}
```

the C++ compiler would not know yet what `T` applies to. When you're working inside the class definition for VisitedSet, you can use `VisitedSet::...` unambiguously, but outside the does not work.

When you're outside the class definition, the syntax requires that you tell the compiler what the template parameters are using the `tempate<class T>` syntax, and then that you tell the compiler where they apply.

In this case, that may seem ambiguous, but consider the following nested case:

```
template<class T>
class Foo {
   template<class R>
   class Bar {
      int getSize();
   };
};
```

Then it's more obvious why you need to be specific:

```
template<class X, class Y>
int Foo<Y>::Bar<X>::getSize() { ...
```

and

```
template<class A, class B>
int Foo<A>::Bar<B>::getSize() { ...
```

are both valid.

So that's why you need

```
template<class T>
int VisitedSet<T>::getSize() {
   return vec.size();
}
```

even in the simpler case shown in the answer you link to.